# c# Entity Framework using rowbegindate in transaction table

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, database-design

I'm a developer that started working with a database architect. He is using a design I've never seen before, that I think will have negative performance implications.

In transaction tables he is using two fields in every table.. rowbegindate and rowenddate. There is a parent table that just a few fields that never changes. This is called a PersonHeader table. That key is used a fk to the child Person table. The Person table's PK is the fk of the PersonHeader table AND the RowBeginDate for that row. To retrieve the current row, I need to always check the for the RowEndDate that is NULL.

I haven't gotten into the details yet of how this will affect performance of Entity Framework, but I suspect that it will not be efficient.

I've worked on a number of projects and have never seen this approach. What are the performance implications of having this many dead records in a transaction table. I don't think there will be many updates, but I would estimate that the database person table could end up having 500,000 rows or more, not to mention the detail tables.

Comment: It might help if you put a diagram of the table schema

Comment: Here's an abbreviation:

Answer (score 1):

When working with applications that have auditing requirements, it is not uncommon to have to maintain historical versions of records.  I have done similar things using (for example, when storing a history of changes to employee records), an EmployeeID and UpdatedOn field as a key so I can get the latest version of the record.

Provided that the tables are properly indexed and that the indexes don't end up being too large because of the composite key, I wouldn't worry about performance or the number of records.  I've worked with tables that contained half a billion records and performance was still fine (rebuilding the indexes took a while though).

You could even create an interceptor from entity framework that would allow you to filter out "dead" records when performing your queries (see [Entity Framework soft delete implementation using database interceptor not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34933981/entity-framework-soft-delete-implementation-using-database-interceptor-not-worki))

Answer (score 0):

PersonHeader
  PersonKey (PK)

Person
  PersonKey (PK, FK)
  RowBeginDate(PK)
  RowEndDate
  (other columns)

(I added this as an answer, since a comment wouldn't take a new line...)
PersonLocation
  LocationTypeKey (PK, FK)
  PersonKey (PK, FK)
  LocationKey (FK)
  RowBeginDate  (not a key)
  RowEndDate

Location
   LocationKey (PK)
   StateKey (FK)
   RowBeginDate (not a key)
   RowEndDate